# Server.app and importing a Let's Encrypt Certificate

Tags: security, keychain, encryption, server.app, serveradmin

I have generated a Let's Encrypt certificate for the subdomain I use for the profile manager website.

I have exported the certificate and imported it into the Server app.

I got the following message when I try to select this certificate.

**Additional access is required to use the selected certificate**
[image: Additional access is required to use the selected certificate.]
I press on Continue. And get this message:

**Services could not be configured to use this certificate**
[image: Services could not be configured to use this certificate.]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you try regenerating the certificates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private keys in the keychain have an Access Control List (ACL) attached to them. You can edit this list using the Keychain Access application.

1. Open Keychain Access and select the System Keychain
2. Select Keys from the Category picker in the sidebar
3. Find and select the Let's Encrypt private key
4. Hit cmd-i (or double click) to open the viewer
5. Select the Access Control tab
6. You may have to authenticate
7. Click the "Allow all applications to access this item" radio button
8. Click the "Save Changes" button.

Then restart Server.app and try setting up the Services again.